# How to get the UID of the current Firebase user?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

How to console the uid. My .ts file is like this:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-candidate-login',
  templateUrl: './candidate-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./candidate-login.component.css']
})
export class CandidateLoginComponent implements OnInit {
user: Observable<firebase.User>;


  constructor(
  public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  private router: Router) {

    this.user = afAuth.authState;
   console.log(this.user.uid);

   }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  login(){
   this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
    this.router.navigate(['/registration']);
  }
}
```

But it shows a error like:

> C:/MyApp/Join/job-site/src/app/candidate-login/candidate-login.component.ts
>   (23,26): Property 'uid' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

How to solve this? Actually, I want to know the current user. I want to console it.

Comment: The error says exactly what's wrong, `uid` does not exist on an Observable, which `user` is. You need to subscribe to it to be able to console log the uid :)

Comment: Try this to see details of your object:

    `console.log(this.user);`

You may be able to see details of the user Observable and find the data you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to subsribe to `afAuth.authState` like this

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
  this.user = user;
  console.log(this.user.uid);
});
```